# How to make a circle progress bar with left side of percentage

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const numb = document.querySelector(".numb");
let counter = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  if (counter == 100) {
    clearInterval();
  } else {
    counter += 1;
    numb.textContent = counter + "%";
  }
}, 80);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  place-items: center;
  background: #dde6f0;
}

.circular {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.circular .inner,
.circular .outer,
.circular .circle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 6;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.circular .inner {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  margin: -40px 0 0 -40px;
  background-color: #dde6f0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.circular .circle {
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.circular .numb {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #4158d0;
}

.circular .bar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  clip: rect(0px, 100px, 100px, 50px);
}

.circle .bar .progress {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  clip: rect(0px, 50px, 100px, 0px);
}

.circle .bar .progress,
.dot span {
  background: #4158d0;
}

.circle .left .progress {
  z-index: 1;
  animation: left 4s linear both;
}

@keyframes left {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

.circle .right {
  z-index: 3;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.circle .right .progress {
  animation: right 4s linear both;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

@keyframes right {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

.circle .dot {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  animation: dot 8s linear both;
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}

.circle .dot span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

@keyframes dot {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    z-index: 4;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    z-index: 4;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Created By CodingNepal -->
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Somehow I got an error, so I comment the title, just uncomment to show -->
  <!-- <title>Circular Progress Bar | CodingNepal</title> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="circular">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
    <div class="outer">
    </div>
    <div class="numb">
      0%</div>
    <div class="circle">
      <div class="dot">
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="bar left">
        <div class="progress">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bar right">
        <div class="progress">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

I want to make a progress bar like the one in the image below. The percentage should be on left side up to 90% and after 90%, it will go to the center.

How can I do that?

[image: expected outcome]

Comment: What have you tried by yourself so far?

Comment: wait I am updating the code @ Rifat Bin Reza

Comment: @Kublai Since the code is provided, it's a valid question following the SO rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can position the `.numb` at the desired place in the beginning, define another css class `.numb-center` which has `top` and `left` `50%` to make it center and add that class to `.numb` when it's your desired percentage in `setInterval` function.

```js
const numb = document.querySelector(".numb");
let counter = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  if (counter == 100) {
    clearInterval();
  } else {
    counter += 1;
    if (counter > 90 && !numb.classList.contains('.numb-center')) {
      numb.classList.add('numb-center')
    }
    numb.textContent = counter + "%";
  }
}, 80);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  place-items: center;
  background: #dde6f0;
}

.circular {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.circular .inner,
.circular .outer,
.circular .circle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 6;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.circular .inner {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  margin: -40px 0 0 -40px;
  background-color: #dde6f0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.circular .circle {
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.circular .numb {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 40%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #4158d0;
}

.numb-center {
  top:50%!important;
  left:50%!important;
}

.circular .bar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  clip: rect(0px, 100px, 100px, 50px);
}

.circle .bar .progress {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  clip: rect(0px, 50px, 100px, 0px);
}

.circle .bar .progress,
.dot span {
  background: #4158d0;
}

.circle .left .progress {
  z-index: 1;
  animation: left 4s linear both;
}

@keyframes left {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

.circle .right {
  z-index: 3;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.circle .right .progress {
  animation: right 4s linear both;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

@keyframes right {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

.circle .dot {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  animation: dot 8s linear both;
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}

.circle .dot span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

@keyframes dot {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    z-index: 4;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    z-index: 4;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Created By CodingNepal -->
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Somehow I got an error, so I comment the title, just uncomment to show -->
  <!-- <title>Circular Progress Bar | CodingNepal</title> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="circular">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
    <div class="outer">
    </div>
    <div class="numb">
      0%</div>
    <div class="circle">
      <div class="dot">
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="bar left">
        <div class="progress">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bar right">
        <div class="progress">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```